# Separate modification logs in pure-ftpd

Tags: pure-ftpd

In /var/log/syslog I see lot of pure-ftpd logs, that indicate "downloaded" action, however I do not see any actions related to moving or deleting files.
I would like to get rid of all "downloaded" logs from /var/log/syslog.
I also would like to create three separate log files for upload, move and delete actions.
How can I do it?